# In Intellij, exploded war exclude jar

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In Intellij Ultimate edition , how to exclude certain jars from exploded war? In my pom.xml section of war plugin I have exclusions on certain jar while building a war, but it is not reflected in exploded war made by intellij. How do I do this? 
Right now , I have to manually remove the lib from project struture->artifacts view.

Comment: Have you tried ty open project as maven project by pointing on pom.xml?

Comment: I have imported the project as a maven project by pointing to pom.xml, but the war created is not using exclusion of jars defined in maven war plugin .

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run Maven clean install command, and restart your server

Comment: This wont solve as the war generated outside intellij excludes jar as defined in maven war plugin. Problem is in exploded war generated inside intellij. I want to run server from intellij